# PHPMailer 6 Composer Not Working

Tags: php, phpmailer

How do I setup PHPMailer properly to get it to work on the server.

I have set it up like in the example provided.

One I upload a file the `upload.php` file is ran but all I get back is a 500 Internal Server Error.

**=============== EDIT ===============**

Problem seems to be PHP version 5.3.3

This setup works on PHP version ^7

.

**server setup**

```
/ root
- uploads.php
- form.html
- vendor (dir)
  - composer (dir)
  - phpmailer (dir)
  - autoload.php
```

.

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

.

**upload.php**

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './vendor/autoload.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

  $mail = new PHPMailer; // <-- error on this line
  echo "after phpmailer"; // <-- does not run

  // phpmailer code here ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPMailer 6.0 and up requires PHP 5.5 as a minimum. You should be using at least PHP 7.0 anyway - but even that reaches end of life in December 2017.